# While integration if one of the limit is $x=\pi/2$ if I substitute $t=\tan x$ then what will be the new limit $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, trigonometry

I want to integrate this:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\text{d}x}{a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x} =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2x\space\text{d}x}{a^2+b^2\tan^2x}$$
Now if I want to substitute $t=\tan x$ what will be the new upper limit for $t$? $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

Comment: When $t$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$, $\tan x$ goes from $0$ to $+\infty$,

Comment: $x$ approaches $\frac\pi2$ from below, so you need to consider $\lim\limits_{x\to\frac\pi2^-}\tan x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $I=\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x) dx$, when $t=\tan x,$
the upper limit is $$\lim_{x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^-} \tan x= \lim_{h \to 0} \tan(\pi/2-h)= \lim_{h \to 0} \cot h= +\infty$$

And for $J=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} f(x) dx$, when $t=\tan x,$
the lower limit is $$\lim_{x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^+} \tan x= \lim_{h \to 0} \tan(\pi/2+h)= \lim_{h \to 0} -\cot h= -\infty$$